# Tree traversal get children of nodes and path to root

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm, tree-traversal

Let's say we have multiple nodes of a tree with different height.
Is there any efficient way to only get the children of the nodes and the path to the root?
This means we can get all nodes, lower than our set of nodes, but to the top we only want the parents until we reach the root. (We don't want the children of the parents).
Because the tree may become very huge, we want to lazily load the children depending on which node we are. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches depending on the constraints, first you can pre-calculate this value for every node in O(N + M). But if the tree is huge then you can't really store those values. So there is second approach, it's easy to find the path from every node to the node (for every node you're going to keep information about the parent only). For the children, you can store pre order traversal of the nodes and everything between the pivot node and the node right to it will be the answer for your question. The overall complexity should be O(N + M)